# Java: Static Method vs Non Static Method

Tags: java, methods, static

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the difference between a static method and a regular method in Java.  I understand there are already a lot of questions relating to this, however none I have seen show a side by side comparison of a static and non static method accomplishing the same task.

This is the static method I have that I'm trying to change to a regular method.

```
public static String getString(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    System.out.print(prompt);
    String s = sc.next();
    sc.nextLine();
    return s;
}
```

And this is where I call it in another class

```
String productCode = Validator.getString(sc, "Enter product code: ");
```

How would I change this to make it a regular method and work when I call it?

Comment: Why are you changing it to a non-static method? What to you expect to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to accomplish the same results using a non static method.

Comment: The reason to create a static method is because you want to call something for a class when you don't have an instance of the class.  Other than that, anything a static method can do, a non-static method can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method can be either `static` or `dynamic`(non `static`). When a method is `static`, it belongs to the class. When a method is dynamic, it belongs to each specific instance of your class. That being said, removing the keyword `static`, creates an instance of your class and calls this method on that object.

In terms of code:

```
public String getString(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{

}

// Use the suitable constructor here.
Validator validator = new Validator();

String productCode = validator.getString(sc, "Enter product code: ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation:

```
public String getString(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    System.out.print(prompt);
    String s = sc.next();
    sc.nextLine();
    return s;
}
```

Usage:

```
new Validator(...).getString(sc , "...");
```